# How to plot different timeseries in one plot in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I have two timeseries datasets for different days.

One has a full day of data for May 2nd.

The other has a full day of data for June 3rd.

I have different times for each. For example: on may 2nd, I have data for times 00h00m02s while for June 3rd I have data for 00h00m04s

How do I plot them on the same figure so I can see how they relate in this 24h period regardless of the day?

How do I keep one x axis and one y axis only for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to take the time only (remove the date) from each of the datasets and plot them together. This way, they would line up on the same x-axis, thus allowing you to plot them on top of each other and easily compare them. Note that I am assuming that you have data for just one day, not multiple days.. A simple example to show this is given below.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# creating fake data
x = ['2023-05-02 01:11:01', 
     '2023-05-02 04:12:22', 
     '2023-05-02 06:41:12', 
     '2023-05-02 10:43:42', 
     '2023-05-02 14:22:11', 
     '2023-05-02 20:21:15']
x = [pd.Timestamp.fromisoformat(date) for date in x]
y = [36, 25, 29, 31, 34, 27]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Datetime': x, 'Value': y})

x = ['2023-06-03 03:12:12', 
     '2023-06-03 06:15:05', 
     '2023-06-03 09:40:13', 
     '2023-06-03 11:20:43', 
     '2023-06-03 13:44:55', 
     '2023-06-03 18:36:11', 
     '2023-06-03 23:51:33']
x = [pd.Timestamp.fromisoformat(date) for date in x]
y = [32, 54, 21, 37, 54, 44, 17]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Datetime': x, 'Value': y})

# make the required change
without_date = df1['Datetime'].apply( lambda d : d.time() )
df1['Datetime'] = without_date
df1['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Datetime'], format="%H:%M:%S")

without_date = df2['Datetime'].apply( lambda d : d.time() )
df2['Datetime'] = without_date
df2['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Datetime'], format="%H:%M:%S")

# Plotting the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df1.Datetime, df1.Value, label="May 2nd", c="tab:blue", marker='o')
ax.plot(df2.Datetime, df2.Value, label="June 3rd", c="tab:orange", marker='d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]